# Overwrite existing Compose key sequences in GNOME

Tags: x11, gnome, wayland, compose-key

I'm using Arch with GNOME 41.3 (Wayland), and I'm trying to rewrite the existing Compose key sequences.

I know that I can define custom sequences in my `~/.XCompose` by `<Multi_key> <key1> <key2> : <output>`; perhaps a potential workaround might be to remap my Compose key to something other than `<Multi_key>`, and then defining my custom sequences that way. But I'm not really sure where to find documentation on this. I would much rather just somehow overwrite the existing sequences.

Thanks.